# Dictionary of classes with different types

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a system that makes spellcasts out of smaller parts of the spell. For example, a damage component and a heal component. For this, I created classes, damage and heal, and I want to store these in a dictionary. I then want to call a function in these classes as they are pulled from the dictionary. The function is always named "Use".

I am having big trouble with getting the classes to be accepted by the dictionary due to each class having a different type. Furthermore, when I call Use, I am told that "Type does not contain a definition for Use".

I've researched around and I can't work out what I'm doing incorrectly.

```cs
public class MakeAbility : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BlockScriptableObject block;

    public IDictionary<string, Type> abilities_parts = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    public PartAttack part_attack;

    private void Start()
    {
        abilities_parts.Add("part_attack", part_attack.GetType(PartAttack));
    }

    public void make_ability()
    {
        foreach (string i in block.ability_parts) // This is a string list of all the component parts. The idea is that For each entry, say "attack", it would call the class in the dictionary with the keyword "attack" and enact it's .Use method.
        {
            abilities_parts[i].Use();
        }
    }
}


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


[System.Serializable]
public class PartAttack
{
    public Targeting target_manager;

    public int block_attack_damage = 0;
    public int block_attack_repeats = 0;

    void Use()
    {
        foreach (Combatant enemy in target_manager.list_of_targetable)
        {
            int repeats = block_attack_repeats;
            while (repeats >= 0)
            {
                enemy.health = enemy.health - block_attack_damage;
                block_attack_repeats -= 1;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you expect to happen when you call `Use` on the value within the dictionary... that's just a `Type`, which as the error message says, doesn't have a `Use` method. Were you expecting to call a static method in the type itself? (e.g. `Damage.Use()` or `Heal.Use()`? It's not clear what `block.ability_parts` is meant to include, either.

Comment: block.abilityparts is a string list of all the component parts. The idea is that For each entry, say "attack", it would call the class in the dictionary with the keyword "attack" and enact it's .Use method.

Comment: I've updated the original question for clarity.

Comment: Use interfaces that define a set of common methods for your abilities. `IAbility` or something like that, this is where `Use` is defined. Make all of your abilities implement this interface. Instantiate the abilities and add them to your dictionary (rather than their Class), so your dictionary is now `<string,IAbility>`

Comment: Exact usecase of [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) or if you already want to be able to have some predefined methods with a certain functionality as well then make it an [abstract class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract)

Answer (score 0):

First of all your implementation of `Use` like

```
void Use()
{
    ...
}
```

automatically makes it `private` so it is not callable from another class. Make it

```
public void Use()
{
    ...
}
```

---

> The function is always named "Use".

This is the exact usecase of [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface)

```
public interface IAbility
{
    // interface method are automatically public
    void Use();
}
```

Now every class implementing that interface **has to** implement the method `Use()` like

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PartAttack, IAbility
{
    public Targeting target_manager;

    public int block_attack_damage = 0;
    public int block_attack_repeats = 0;

    // has to implement this because of IAbility
    public override void Use()
    {
        foreach (Combatant enemy in target_manager.list_of_targetable)
        {
            int repeats = block_attack_repeats;
            while (repeats >= 0)
            {
                enemy.health = enemy.health - block_attack_damage;
                block_attack_repeats -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you rather already want to be able to have some predefined methods with a certain functionality and make the classes also share some of the same fields as well then make it an [abstract class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract)

```
[System.Serializable]
public abstract class Ability
{
    // this can not be changed or accessed not even by any inheritor
    private float aValueOnlyThisClassCanSee;

    // this can changed/accessed by inheritors but not from the outside
    protected string SomeProtectedValue;

    // this can accessed/changed by everyone
    public Targeting target_manager;

    // the same keywords can be used on methods ... I skip this ;)

    // This method HAS TO BE implemented by every inheritor
    public abstract void Use();

    // This method CAN BE implemented in order to extend or overwrite it by inhertors
    public virtual void SaySomething()
    {
        Debug.Log("I basically do nothing.");
    }
}
```

Now you inherit like

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PartAttack : Ability
{
    // inherit target_manager and can use it in every inheritor

    public int block_attack_damage = 0;
    public int block_attack_repeats = 0;

    // Has to be implemented otherwise throws compiler-error
    public override void Use()
    {
        foreach (Combatant enemy in target_manager.list_of_targetable)
        {
            int repeats = block_attack_repeats;
            while (repeats >= 0)
            {
                enemy.health = enemy.health - block_attack_damage;
                block_attack_repeats -= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // CAN BE implemented in order to extend
    public override void SaySomething()
    {
        Debug.Log("I'm creating some debug logs but ..");

        base.SaySomething();
    }
}
```

---

Now depending on with which one you go your dictionary is either

```
public Dictionary<string, IAbility> abilities_parts = new Dictionary<string, IAbility>();
```

or

```
public Dictionary<string, Ability> abilities_parts = new Dictionary<string, Ability>();
```